# How to fill out a textfield within a form on a webpage from a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

So far I have got an extension that lists out the webpage the user is on and a button. The button should, when clicked, fill in the textfield with "testing123".

On the webpage where I am testing the form has a id and name "form" and the textfield has an id and name "body".

If I could get some help filling in this textfield or a general textfield it would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the files I have so far:

**manifest.json**

```
    {
      "name": "Extension Menu",
      "version": "1.0",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "description": "My extension",
      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_menu": "Menu",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
      },
      "icons": {
        "128": "icon.png"
      },
      "permissions": [
          "tabs", "http://*/*", "activeTab"
        ]
    }
```

**popup.html**

```
<p id="currentLink">Loading ...</p>
<hr />
<ul id="savedLinks"></ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script><br>
<button type="button" onclick="fill in text box with the word 'testing123'">Go!</button>
```

**popup.js**

```
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
      // $("#body").val("testing123");
      // document.getElementById('body').value = 'testing123';
      document.getElementById('currentLink').innerHTML = tab.url;
    });
```

I have tried using:

1. `$("#body").val("testing123");`
2. `document.getElementById('body').value = 'testing123';`

but they do not seem to be working.

Comment: where is it in your code #body? write it in your sample popup.httml

Comment: #body is in the tab where the search bar is and its id/name is body. Would you like to see the code for the form on the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the webpage directly from `popup`. You should use [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to do this. `Content scripts` run in the context of the webpage.

Add this to your manifest :

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://www.example.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery.js",
                "myscript.js"
            ]
        },
```

**myscript.js** :

```
$("#body").val("testing123");

document.getElementById('body').value = 'testing123';
```

Comment: thank you! that seems to work when the page is first loaded. Do you know how I could do it so the value is loaded in the textfield once the button is clicked?

Comment: @ayaz15m : Either you can directly add the button to the page through this content script and add `onclick event` to it, OR , you should use (message passing)[https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging]. In message passing button click on `popup` will send a message to the `content script` to run the onclick event on the webpage.

Comment: would the onclick event occur when the extension button is clicked or the button in the popup. I would like it to occur when the button in the popup is clicked. Would it work the same as what you described?

Comment: Can give my button and id="btn" and put the contents of myscript.js inside of:
$('#btn').click(function(){  //current code });
Would something like that work?