# How to fill data to Facebook textbox with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create an Chrome extension which can help me:

- Fill some data(text/link) to textbox of Facebook Group then click to Post( I mean: Post status Facebook using exention not using my hand)
- It's not a `<textarea>` so i can't use: `$('textarea')` to set value of that textbox.

**Example**:

[image]

Please help me! Thank so much

Answer (score 0):

manifest

```
 "js": [
                "jquery.js",
                "script.js"
            ]
```

script.js

```
$("#body").val("testing123");

document.getElementById('body').value = 'testing123';
```

See details on how to implement the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107229/how-to-fill-out-a-textfield-within-a-form-on-a-webpage-from-a-chrome-extension?rq=1)

There is another way using [Chrome Extensions: Insert text into textfield when clicking button in pop-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515557/chrome-extensions-insert-text-into-textfield-when-clicking-button-in-pop-up)